# PostgreSQL CAST(x AS typename) or x::typename

Tags: postgresql

Should I use `cast(x as typename)` or `x::typename` in PostgreSQL?

I was not able to find any documentation for `x::typename` version of cast except one sentence in [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) ("*By default, a cast can be invoked only by an explicit cast request, that is an explicit CAST(x AS typename) or x::typename construct."*

Is the only difference that `cast(x as typename)` is in [sql-standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) while `x::typename` is not?

I do prefer `x::typename` all the time as it is shorter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x::typename` is postgresql specific. If you prefer it and it doesn't have to work on non postgresql databases you can use it.

The manual for casting is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). As you will see there is a third style but it is not recommended.

Comment: Yes. The differences in typenames makes the issue of porting a moot point *in many cases*.  However if the type names are compatible between postures and another DBMS then `cast` can be but `::` is unlikely to be.

Comment: Does it mean that `::` support can be removed in some future PostgreSQL version? We are not using other DBMSs, but we do upgrade frequently to the latest PostgreSQL version.

Comment: They might but I don't think it is likely. Also they will probably first deprecate it's use to give everybody time to update there code. Also that kind of changes will only happen on major versions ie from 9.2 to 9.3 not on maintenance updates.